# Is there a cross-platform SCSS compiling and bundling that works for Blazor solutions?

Tags: c#, css, sass, compilation, bundling-and-minification

I have a setup where both a Linux OS and Windows are used to work on Blazor WASM Hosted solutions and one thing that we can't match on Linux is the SCSS compiling and *.css bundling.

On Windows it's a matter of two VS extensions "Builder & Minifier" and "Web Compiler 2022", each with its own config file(and on Linux there're no such utilities gives that JetBrains Rider is used).

Did someone figure out a solution for this problem?(if possible, leaving out any dependency on node.js)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the nuget package `DartSassBuilder` https://github.com/deanwiseman/DartSassBuilder? at least the scss compiling part can be done with it.

Comment: Unfortunately that whole chain of projects is going deprecated.

Comment: @Eugene do you have any information about the deprication? I know that the LibSassBuilder project is deprecated (since lib-sass is getting depricated) and replaced by DartSassbuilder. The DartSassBuilder depends on the DartSassHost which does not mention any deprication in their readme.